# Dyna-Q vs "Imagination-Augmented Agents for Deep Reinforcement Learning"

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

What is the difference between the two?

Both use a world model, both based on reinforcement learning.
Is it accurate to say that in Dyna Q, the world model only use for **providing extra simulation** sample to "fine-tune" the model-free agent, where as in [Imagination-Augmented Agents for Deep Reinforcement Learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.06203), the world model actually factor into the **Agent's decision making process?**

Comment: This site is for questions that are directly about implementation / programming issues. I think the question will be more on-topic on https://ai.stackexchange.com/ (or, possibly, https://stats.stackexchange.com/)